# PostgreSQL database connection in asp.net mvc and Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, postgresql, npgsql

I'm attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL database from my ASP.NET MVC site. The format for the view and model work for both SQL Server and MySQL, so I shouldn't have problems there, as far as I can tell.

The application is throwing a `System.ArgumentException` in the `System.Data.dll` and returns an error:

> Keyword not supported: metadata" "Parameter name: keyword

on the webpage.

That it is using the `System.Data.dll` seems wrong, but I can't corroborate this.

How can I connect to PostgreSQL in this manner?

I have Nuget installed Npgsql 3.0.5 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.0.5.

Please let me know if I left off vital information.

Relevant `web.config` information is as follows:

```
<add name="PostgreSQLConnectionString" 
     connectionString="
     metadata=res://*/Models.Test.csdl|res://*/Models.Test.ssdl|res://*/Models.Test.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=localhost:5432\;
     initial catalog=Test;
     integrated security=False;
     user id=username;
     password=password;
     multipleactiveresultsets=True;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="Npgsql" />

<provider invariantName="Npgsql" 
          type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql">
</provider>

<remove invariant="Npgsql" />
<add name="Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" 
     invariant="Npgsql" 
     description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" 
     type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the provider will be something like `Npgsql`, not `System.Data.SqlClient`, and I'm not sure the Postgres driver supports MARS. [Here's an example](http://rob.conery.io/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/) of a Code-first configuration.

Comment: @StuartLC That a piece of it all, all the provider names are Npgsql.  I'm not sure why its references the System.Data.SqlClient at all.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above answer from @Ram Pukar: Make sure you define the correct table- and schema-name in your models. The default schema in Postgres is "public", whereas MsSQL (and EF) expects "dbo".

If you are using delimiter-separated words for column names, you can stop EF complaining by adding column aliases to your definiton, e.g.:

```
 [Table("your_table", Schema = "your_schema")]
    public class YourModelName
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id_colum_name")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("some_string_colum_name")]
        public string SomeString{ get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll reinvestigate this when I have the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

```
pm> Install-Package Npgsql -Version 2.2.0
pm> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

> Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=postgres;password=admin;database=api_db" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
           invariant="Npgsql"
           support="FF"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

> Model

```
PGDbContext.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PgDemo.Models
{
    public class PGDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public PGDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "DefaultConnectionString") { }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> Usr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Users.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PgDemo.Models
{
    [Table("users", Schema = "public")]
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userpass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
using PgDemo.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PgDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        PGDbContext _context;
        public HomeController()
        {
            _context = new PGDbContext();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Usr.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

> Views

```
@using PgDemo.Models
@model IEnumerable<Users>
<table border="1">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userpass)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: JUST saw this.  I will try to play with it some today if possible.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting "42P01: relation "dbo.PostgreSQLTests" does not exist" as an error.

Problem seems to be that its looking for a SQL Server table: the PostgreSQL is formatted "Test"."PostgreSQLTests";

Answer (score 0):

I use this in the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConnection"  connectionString="server=localhost;port=5432;user id=myUser;password=myPassword;database=myDatabaseName"    providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Just a friendly reminder to `NUGet` "Npgsql" and "Npgsql for Entity Framework 6". BOTH the "Npgsql" and the "Npgsql Entity Framework 6" are on version 3.0.4 (please check).

Comment: web.config settings don't seem to make a difference, but I will double check the versions for Npgsql and Npgsql Entity Framework.  I think Npgsql is 3.0.5, but I'll make sure.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, both were installed using 3.0.5.